# Recover password for local user admin account in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, password-recovery

I'm putting this question after trying everything.

```
Laptop Make- Lenovo Thinkpad E470
OS - Windows 10 Pro
```

**Issue** - Lost the password for the admin account in Windows 10 (`Local User`). There is access to only a `guest account` which has zero admin rights. *Re-install windows* and *Reset system* doesn't work.

Attempts.

1. Tried to reset password from **password recovery tool** from a laptop shop but they failed since the bootable device wasn't recognized.
2. Made a bootable pen drive with **Windows 10 ISO image** to re-install windows but same issue. Bootable device wasn't recognized. Changed all the basic and advanced options from the BIOS i.e. *Disable Secure boot, Legacy Mode, Changing boot order.* Followed almost 50 youtube videos after which *USB Cruzer Blade* started showing but it did not boot from the boot menu, it keeps on getting back to the same console.
3. Tried to reset the system from 'Reset system option' with Clean entire system' selection after clicking shift + restart. But the reset failed after sometime saying- `Some error occurred while restting, No changes made.
4. Also tried -> Troubleshooting -> System image Recovery. but it gets back to normal windows boot after restart.
5. Tried --> Troubleshooting --> Command Prompt but it again asks the password for admin account after restart.
6. Tried all the options available after Shift + Restart but can not bypass the Local user admin password. In every step it is required.

Now I'm not sure what to do. I'm **NOT** worried of the data in the system. I just want to either:

1. Recover the lost password for the local user account. OR
2. Make a clean Windows install with fresh local user accounts created.

Please give a solution considering above scenario. The guest account for which I've access is useless since you can not install anything or open any console due to lack of admin rights.

Comment: Guest account is disabled and unusable on Windows 10. It cannot be used. It’s not clear what account your actually accessing but it cannot be the built in guest account.  Is the account your attempting to us the built-in Administrator account?

Comment: Thanks but its sorted now. Had to pay a lot of money to an online system hacking agent which was cracked then

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest is to *remove* the Admin password, thereby allowing the system to boot *without* requiring a password. After removing the password, go to Users CPL and reapply a local password. Luckily, you state this is a *local* account, so easy to do -- if it were through a Microsoft account, you'd need to get their assistance.

There are [numerous tools to *reset*, i.e., remove, the password](https://alternativeto.net/software/reset-windows-password/), but the guidance below is [using Ubuntu](https://www.iseepassword.com/reset-windows-password-with-ubuntu-free.html), which I've found useful.

- Make a [Live Ubuntu USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), using an Ubuntu ISO and [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or similar application to create the USB (which should be formatted FAT32).
- [Set BIOS so your PC recognizes the USB media.](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500222-recommended-ways-to-enter-bios-boot-menu-thinkpad-thinkcentre-thinkstation)  Likely, just unset Fast Boot and change bot order; Secure Boot may be left as is, in my experience.
- Boot from the USB drive - do not bother to install the OS to your drive.
- [Install *chntpw*](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/chntpw), used to remove the password.
- Browse in Ubuntu to C:/Windows/System32/config [yes, *forward* slashes in Linux].
- Right-click on the file *SAM* in that folder and select *Properties*.
- Copy the *Location* shown in properties, e.g.

  /media/123456abcd/Windows/System32/config (where *123456abcd* is a drive identifier)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open *Terminal*
- In *Terminal*, enter

  cd /media/<drive_identifier>/WINDOWS/system32/config
- Enter the following to remove the password:

  sudo chntpw -u Administrator SAM